# Where is the 'View Page' link when you create a CMS page with Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

Where to find the 'View Page' link when you create a CMS page with Prestashop?

In Wordpress you can see the View Page a the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is `Save and preview` button.

[image: Save and preview button]

Comment: @Indrè This button doens't work for me. It just "save and stays".